# Why sometimes my load function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So in my app i'm opening a dialog and load some content into it. Most of the times it works fine, but sometimes it just doesn't load content. Here is how i do it.

```
$('#popup_background').css('z-index', 101);
    $('#popup').empty();  
    $('#popup').dialog('open');
    $('#popup').load('<?php echo site_url("popupContent"); ?>',{'id':new_id}, function()    
    {
        $('#popup').bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
            $('#popup_background').css('z-index', 99);
     });
    }

    );
```

If i check in firebug i always get content back but sometimes it's just not showed in dialog. And if that happens my popup_background doesn't get changed z-index which means that dialogclose isn't getting called.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the above code, so I'd say either it's something else in your Javascript or your PHP code.

Comment: Hmm i don't know what, like i said i get correct response from php, it's just not showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be sometimes your `load` function is not completed.. why don't you keep your dialog `open` after `load`function  is completed.. so if incase load function does not execute.. you atleast don't have a blank dialog opening.. :) :)

```
$('#popup').load('<?php echo site_url("popupContent"); ?>',{'id':new_id}, function()    
{
    $('#popup').dialog('open');
    $('#popup').bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
        $('#popup_background').css('z-index', 99);
 });
}
```

Comment: the dialog open is called before the load.. so there is no guarantee that the `popup` div will have the content by the time `load` gets and appends it..so thats why you are gettin the blank popup...anyways its best you keep the open inside the `load` complete so that you can be sure,, the dialog open is called after the load complete ... and i think this should solve your issue.. let me know if it exists ...

Comment: wow, it seems that it realy newer happens again. I thought that load will load content even if dialog is already oppened. Anyway thanks a lot! However now i need to find a way to show user something is loading :D

Comment: yes.. :)....show loading div before load function and hide it whn load completes..as simple as it can get....:):)..